# Math equation problem - fitting wallpapers on a wall

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, logarithms, exponential-function

I am building up a java program but don't have the right idea on how to resolve its math problem.

The tasks is to cover the wall with wallpaper.

The wall has width $a$ (input) and height $b$ (input). I can use wallpaper with dimensions 1 × 1, 2 × 2 up to $2^n$ × $2^n$ ($n$ is an input). I want to "dress" the wall with wallpapers with the biggest wallpapers available and as few of them as possible.

The output I need is just a number of wallpapers used.

**An example:** 3 inputs are: $a = 22$, $b = 29$, and $n = 3$. 
This means the the wall is 22 × 29 and the max wallpaper is sized $2^3$ × $2^3$ (8 by 8). The wall should then be filled like: 
[image: example for a = 22, b = 29, n = 3]

So the output (number of needed wallpapers) would be 53.

Since $a$ and $b$ can be large (up to $10^18$), the best thing would be do NOT use loops (recursive equations) for it. The $n$ can be up to 30.

Comment: What does $n=3$ mean?  I don't see it used.  Why don't you combine four of the $8 \times 8$s into $16 \times 16$?  Even with $a$ and $b$ that large, if each loop cuts it in half you only do $54$ or so loops, which is tiny.  MathJax hint:  for multicharacter exponents, put them in braces, so 10^{18} gives $10^{18}$ instead of 10^18 which gives $10^18$